# Extracting Rows by specific keyword in Python (Without using Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, csv, filter, extract

My csv file looks like this:-

```
ID,Product,Price

1,Milk,20
2,Bottle,200
3,Mobile,258963
4,Milk,24
5,Mobile,10000
```

My code of extracting row is as follow :-

```
def search_data():

    fin = open('Products/data.csv')
    word = input() # "Milk"
    found = {}
    for line in fin:

        if word in line:

            found[word]=line

    return found

search_data()
```

While I run this above code I got output as :-

```
{'Milk': '1,Milk ,20\n'}
```

I want If I search for "Milk" I will get all the rows which is having "Milk" as Product.

**Note:- Do this in only Python don't use Pandas**

Expected output should be like this:-

```
[{"ID": "1", "Product": "Milk ", "Price": "20"},{"ID": "4", "Product": "Milk ", "Price": "24"}]
```

Can anyone tell me where am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In your script every time you assign `found[word]=line` it will overwrite the value that was before it. Better approach is load all the data and then do filtering:

If `file.csv` contains:

```
ID     Product     Price

1      Milk        20
2      Bottle      200
3      Mobile      10,000
4      Milk        24
5      Mobile      15,000
```

Then this script:

```
#load data:
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    lines =  [line.split() for line in map(str.strip, f_in) if line]
    data = [dict(zip(lines[0], l)) for l in lines[1:]]

# print only items with 'Product': 'Milk'
print([i for i in data if i['Product'] == 'Milk'])
```

Prints only items with `Product` == `Milk`:

```
[{'ID': '1', 'Product': 'Milk', 'Price': '20'}, {'ID': '4', 'Product': 'Milk', 'Price': '24'}]
```

---

EDIT: If your data are separated by commas (`,`), you can use `csv` module to read it:

`File.csv` contains:

```
ID,Product,Price

1,Milk ,20
2,Bottle,200
3,Mobile,258963
4,Milk ,24
5,Mobile,10000
```

Then the script:

```
import csv

#load data:
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f_in:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    lines = [line for line in csvreader if line]
    data = [dict(zip(lines[0], l)) for l in lines[1:]]

# # print only items with 'Product': 'Milk'
print([i for i in data if i['Product'].strip() == 'Milk'])
```

Prints:

```
[{'ID': '1', 'Product': 'Milk ', 'Price': '20'}, {'ID': '4', 'Product': 'Milk ', 'Price': '24'}]
```

Comment: It shows me Error in ```print([i for i in data if i['Product'] == 'Milk'])``` as ```KeyError: 'Product'```.

Comment: @UrviSoni Has `file.csv` _exactly_ the same structure as I posted in answer or do you supply your own data? The header is important in this case.

Comment: Yes, @Andrej Kesely Also while I am try this ```print(data)``` output of this line is :- ```[{'ID,Product,Price': '1,Milk'}, {'ID,Product,Price': '2,Bottle,200'}, {'ID,Product,Price': '3,Mobile,258963'}, {'ID,Product,Price': '4,Milk'}, {'ID,Product,Price': '5,Mobile,10000'}]``` . It didn't print price of milk.

Comment: @UrviSoni Your data is not like in question. The cells are separated by commas (`,`), not with space or tabs. Can you edit your question and add how the data looks like inside the file - I can use `csv` module to read it, but need to know the structure.

Comment: Sure ! Editing my Question !